# How does the blocked thread handle timer signal for timer created with SIGEV_THREAD_ID

Tags: timer, posix

I am working on a Posix timer functionality for my application where individual threads create timers using event notification method of SIGEV_THREAD_ID so that the timer signal (SIGRTMIN+1) can be handled with the specified handler in the respective thread context. I need to understand the invocation of signal handler in the thread context when the thread is in different state. For example, if some individual thread blocks on a message queue or a semaphore after creating the timer and the timer expires, how will the signal handling occur? I understand that if the thread has been executing, then it would be preempted and the signal handler will be called within the context of that thread. But if the thread is blocked as mentioned above, what really happens?
Any help in understanding the internal on this is highly appreciated.